# Como puedo guardar los cambios en una tabla con javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

Estoy tratando de editar unos datos en una tabla con javascript pero al momento de trtar de guardar estos datos me devuelve a la pagina de inicio y lo que necesito es que me guarde lo cambios sin tener que recargar la pagina

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al momento de dar en editar los datos son puestos en los input en la misma tabla para poder editarlos, pero en darle en aceptar me devuelve a la pagina de inicio, lo que necesito es que me mantenga en la pagina para poder enviar todo el formulario a la base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el script que estoy usando para poder editar

```
    <script>
    var editando = false;



    function transformarEnEditable(nodo) {

        //El nodo recibido es SPAN

        if (editando == false) {

            var nodoTd = nodo.parentNode; //Nodo TD

            var nodoTr = nodoTd.parentNode; //Nodo TR

            var nodoContenedorForm = document.getElementById('contenedorForm'); //Nodo DIV

            var nodosEnTr = nodoTr.getElementsByTagName('td');

            var Nombre = nodosEnTr[0].textContent;
            var Unidad = nodosEnTr[1].textContent;
            var Precio = nodosEnTr[2].textContent;
            var Cantidad = nodosEnTr[3].textContent;
            var Descuento = nodosEnTr[4].textContent;
            var Observacion = nodosEnTr[5].textContent;

            var nuevoCodigoHtml = '<td>' + Nombre + '</td>' +

                '<td>' + Unidad + '</td>' +

                '<td>' + Precio + '</td>' +

                '<td><input type="text" name="Cantidad" id="Cantidad" value="' + Cantidad + '" size="5"</td>' +

                '<td><input type="text" name="Descuento" id="Descuento" value="' + Descuento + '" size="5"</td>' +

                '<td><input type="text" name="Observacion" id="Observacion" value="' + Observacion + '" size="15"</td> <td>En edición</td>';



            nodoTr.innerHTML = nuevoCodigoHtml;



            nodoContenedorForm.innerHTML = 'Pulse Aceptar para guardar los cambios o cancelar para anularlos' +

                '<form name = "formulario" method="get" onsubmit="capturarEnvio()" onreset="anular()">' +

                '<input class="boton" type = "submit" value="Aceptar"> <input class="boton" type="reset" value="Cancelar">';

            editando = "true";
        }

        else {
            alert('Solo se puede editar una línea. Recargue la página para poder editar otra');

        }

    }


    function anular() {

        window.location.reload();

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Agrega el codigo del boton que ejecuta esa funcion

Comment: esa funcion no esta ya que solo arma el form a la base

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar hacer un preventDefault si es que tu botón de guardar esta ejecutando un Submit

```js
function guardar(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  // ...resto de tu codigo
}
```

Fuentes: [Mozilla Docs. Prevent Default](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).